# ICal not updating existing event

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I have created two ical files, one is ical with method:request, and another one is ical with method cancel. When I import them into my outlook calendar, both of them are creating new event.(If I specify the meeting with the status:CANCELLED it is not updating the existing one, but it's creating new one with cancelled status). Both of the icals have the same UID. Do You know how to change that? Or how to update existing meeting via ical file in outlook. However on google calendar everything works as expected, so I am curious whether outlook has some strange behaviour specified for ical files.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST/CANCEL(in cancel ical)
PRODID:prod
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Warsaw
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Warsaw
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20191231T160000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20191231T170000
LOCATION:Loc
SUMMARY:summ
DESCRIPTION:description
SEQUENCE:0/1 (in cancel ical)
CLASS:PUBLIC
UID:SAME_UID
DTSTAMP:20191227T090501Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-3.2.5, a CANCEL to a REQUEST, must include all the attendees:

```
ATTENDEE        0+     MUST include all "Attendees" being removed
                       the event. MUST include all "Attendees" if
                       the entire event is cancelled.
```

If you don't have attendees, a PUBLISH may be more appropriate.  Then any items you remove in this published feed, are removed from the calendar.